# Python:create combination of two columns containing lists as their values in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with lists in its columns and I am trying to figure out a way to find the combination of the two lists. The key thing is that the ID must be mapped to right combination -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,['a','b','c'],['l','m']],[2,['d','e','f'],['n','o']]],columns = ['id','col1','col2'])
```

The result should be -

```
   id col1  col2
----------------
0   1   a   l
1   1   a   m
2   1   b   l
3   1   b   m
4   1   c   l
5   1   c   m
6   2   d   n
7   2   d   o
8   2   e   n
9   2   e   o
10  2   f   n
11  2   f   o
```

I am new to python and have tried exploring itertools library and its product functions, but I couldn't understand how to exactly get this format of the output.

Comment: ``df.explode('col1').explode('col2')``, [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` with list comprehension to construct the combinations:

```
print (pd.DataFrame([(a,*x) for a,b,c in df.to_numpy() 
                     for x in product(b,c)],
                     columns=df.columns))

    id col1 col2
0    1    a    l
1    1    a    m
2    1    b    l
3    1    b    m
4    1    c    l
5    1    c    m
6    2    d    n
7    2    d    o
8    2    e    n
9    2    e    o
10   2    f    n
11   2    f    o
```

Alternatively, you can use unpacking if you do not want to explicitly, say, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, for the columns :

```
from itertools import product, chain

pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(product([a], *rest) 
                                 for a, *rest in df.to_numpy()),
             columns=df.columns
             )
```